# Ask window manager to place matplotlib plot windows "always on top"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, window-managers, x11, xfce

The question sounds simple, I'm currently using Xfce4 under Linux and I want all the interactive plots popped out of python/matplotlib scripts, to appear **On Top** of all other windows

Basically I want *XWindows* to recognize those figure windows and then apply common window operations. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using pyplot.show() to show the window?  Are you using the default gtk backend?

Comment: I use various backends, but yep, majorly it's gtk; I used almost exclusively `pyplot.show()` for display.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you are after, but if you were generating your own GTK gui you can use:

```
win.set_keep_above(True)
```

As in:

```
import gtk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas

win = gtk.Window()
win.connect("destroy", lambda x: gtk.main_quit())
win.set_default_size(400,300)
win.set_title("Some Window")

f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
a.plot([1,2,3,4,5])

canvas = FigureCanvas(f)
win.add(canvas)
win.set_keep_above(True)

win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: interesting, I'll give it a shot and see how it goes.